# How to use country_select as select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using country_select in form_for is easy.

But now, I want to use it as a way to filter by country.

Can you point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using [stefanpenner/country_select](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select) `country_select` then

```
<%= select_tag "country", options_from_collection_for_select(ISO3166::Country.countries.sort_by(&:name), 'un_locode', 'name') %>
```

or if you are using [jim/carmen-rails](https://github.com/jim/carmen-rails) `country_select` then

```
<%= select_tag "country", options_from_collection_for_select(Carmen::Country.all.sort_by(&:name), 'code', 'name') %>
```

Hope this would be helpful

Comment: I'm using the first one. I pasted it on my page and the list of countries appears so I'm very happy. But from here, I have no idea what should I do next to really implement what I wanted to do which is to filter by country. Can you teach me or at least show me helpful resources? Thanks :)

Comment: is it possible to pass `priority_countries: ["GB", "FR", "DE"]` into there?