# my search form using f.country_select and params[:country]... is not being passed correctly into the query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is what I need the query string to look like to work:

> users?utf8=✓&country=US&nil=Search

this is what is being passed now:

> users?utf8=✓&%2Fusers%5Bcountry%5D=US&nil=Search

this is my search form code. I don't know how to get `params[:country]` out of it.

```
<%= form_for users_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.country_select(:country, include_blank: true, priority_countries: ["GB", "US", "CA", "AU", "TH", "JP", "IN", "FR", "DE"]) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => "nil", :id => "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
@users = User.countryname(params[:country]).paginate(page: params[:page]) if params[:country].present?
```

this is with use of the [country_select gem.](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select)

Comment: You need to provide the `model` instance to `form_for`, you can use `form_tag`, if you have the `user` instance available just use, `form_for(@user, method: :get) do  |f|`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag users_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag "country", options_from_collection_for_select(ISO3166::Country.countries, 'un_locode', 'name'), :include_blank => true %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => "nil", :id => "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

[How to use country_select as select_tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35175579/how-to-use-country-select-as-select-tag/35178156#35178156)

Answer (score 0):

What is passed is, actually, `/users[:country]`. `users_path` returns `/users` and `country` is wrapped inside that `/users`.
Try `form_for :query, url: users_path, method: :get do |f|` and fetch selected country with `params[:query][:country]` (don't forget that `params[:query]` could be nil sometimes, so you might want to have, say, `params[:query].try(:[], :country])`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `model` instance to `form_for`, you can use `form_tag`, if you have the `user` instance available just use if you want to submit the form for one specific user (This will select the path automatically depending on what is `@user`),

```
form_for(@user, method: :get) do |f|
  f.country_select(:country, include_blank: true, priority_countries: ["GB", "US", "CA", "AU", "TH", "JP", "IN", "FR", "DE"])
  submit_tag "Search", :name => "nil", :id => "submit"
end
```

else, if you want to submit on `index path` with `country` as simple parameter use

```
form_tag(users_path, method: :get) do |f|
  country_select(:country, include_blank: true, priority_countries: ["GB", "US", "CA", "AU", "TH", "JP", "IN", "FR", "DE"])
  submit_tag "Search", :name => "nil", :id => "submit"
end
```

Comment: everything is being passed - at=info method=GET path="/users?utf8=%E2%9C%93&country%5B%7B%3Ainclude_blank%3D%3Etrue%2C+%3Apriority_countries%3D%3E%5B%22GB%22%2C+%22US%22%2C+%22CA%22%2C+%22AU%22%2C+%22TH%22%2C+%22JP%22%2C+%22IN%22%2C+%22FR%22%2C+%22DE%22%5D%7D%5D=US&nil=Search"

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss What do you mean?

Comment: that is the query string in the browser after selecting a country from the dropdown list and hitting submit.